# Updating DOM attached to directive without refreshing it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that contains some text and a video tag

```
    app.directive('ngAzuremediaplayer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        priority: 10,
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.hideapprove = attrs.hideapprove;
            scope.hidereject = attrs.hidereject;
            scope.hideinfo = attrs.hideinfo;
            scope.hidedelete = attrs.hidedelete;
            scope.hidecard = attrs.hidecard;
            scope.hidethumb = attrs.hidethumb;

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngBind, function (newvalue) {
                var myOptions = {
                    "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
                    "logo": { "enabled": false },
                    controls: true,
                    autoplay: false,
                    poster: scope.video.ThumbnailUri,

                }
                var myPlayer = null;
                if (scope.video.AMSUri != null) {
                    myPlayer = amp(document.getElementById(scope.video.RowKey), myOptions);
                    myPlayer.src([
                            {
                                "src": scope.video.AMSUri,
                                "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
                            }
                    ]);
                }
                else {
                    if (scope.video.RawVideoUri != null) {
                        myPlayer = amp(document.getElementById(scope.video.RowKey), myOptions);
                        myPlayer.src([
                              {
                                  "src": scope.video.RawVideoUri,
                                  "type": "video/mp4"
                              }
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        templateUrl: '/app/templates/VideoControl.html',
    }
});
```

Here is the used template file

```
<div class="monster-admin-video monster-section-link">
<div class="monster-card">
    <div class="monster-card-content" ng-hide="hidecard">
        <h5 class="monster-card-title" style="margin-top: 0px;">{{video.ChannelName}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="monster-admin-video-player embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="">
        <video id="{{video.RowKey }}" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered embed-responsive-item" controls>
            <p class="amp-no-js">
                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
            </p>
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="monster-admin-action-buttons">
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-hide="hideapprove" ng-click="vm.approve(video)"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-lg"></i></a>
        <!--<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-hide="hidereject" ng-click="vm.reject(video)"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg"></i></a>-->
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-hide="hideinfo" ng-click="vm.info(video)"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-hide="hidedelete" ng-click="vm.delete(video)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-hide="hidethumb" ng-click="vm.createThumbnail(video)"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="monster-admin-video-caption">
        <div style="float:left">
            {{video.EncodingStatus}}
        </div> <div style="float:right">
            {{video.VideoProgress}}
        </div>
        <br />
        <p class="lead monster-admin-video-title" ng-bind="video.Title" data-ellipsis></p>
        <p class="monster-admin-video-desc" ng-bind="video.Description" data-ellipsis></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is working as expected, but now I want to be able to update EncodingStatus and VideoProgress on some interval. I have this regular javascript function that does this

```
      function populateVideoStatus(data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function (video, key) {
            if (document.getElementById(video.RowKey) != null) {
                var encodingStatus = "";
                var videoProgress = ""
                switch (video.VideoStatusId) {
                    case 0:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Not Uploaded";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Uploading";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Upload Complete";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Encoding Started";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Encoding Scheduled";
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Encoding Processing";
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Encoding Complete";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Thumbnail Generation Scheduled";
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Thumbnail Generation Processing";
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Thumbnail Generation Complete";
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "Video Ready for Viewing";
                        break;
                    default:
                        video.EncodingStatus = "";
                        break;
                }

                if (video.VideoProgress == "100%") {
                    video.VideoProgress = "";
                }

                var videoPlayer = document.getElementById(video.RowKey);
                var temp = videoPlayer.parentElement.parentElement.children[3];
                temp.children[0].innerHTML = video.EncodingStatus;
                temp.children[1].innerHTML = video.VideoProgress;
            }
        }, log);
        return data;
    }
```

and I call it like so

```
   function getVideoForReview(call) {
        return datacontext.getVideosPage(1, vm.pageSize, vm.CurrentPage, call, '').then(function (data) {
            vm.Users = common.getVideoUsers(data);
            return vm.videos = common.populateVideoStatus(data);
        });
    }
```

Here is the interval function that is called

```
     function doTimeout() {
        getVideoForReview(true).then(function (data) {
            setTimeout(doTimeout, 5000);
        });
    }
```

Here all I am doing is updating the DOM of the div that holds those 2 values. What happens, is that everytime my interval that calls populateVideoStatus(), it refreshes the directive, and my video player is reinitialized, which is not ideal for obvious reasons. I know that this is expected behavior because of the $watch I have, but I am having trouble getting this to work. Here in a nutsell is what I want to do.

- Load directive and video on page load
- Interval updates status (makes an api call) and updates DOM

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are targeting the correct element with `temp`?

To me it looks like you are setting `temp` to the `monster-admin-video-player` div instead of the `monster-admin-video-caption` div.

Maybe try:

```
var temp = videoPlayer.parentElement.parentElement.children[3];
```

Also, is it possible that the `populateVideoStatus` function could just set the `$scope.video.EncodingStatus` and `$scope.video.VideoProgress` that you already have in your template rather than doing direct DOM innerHTML?

Comment: You are right about the value of temp, I copied some code where I took the div out of the template but didn't show the right JS code. I initially tried to put it in scope, but the video was refreshing. I have updated the OP with my original code

Comment: does it "just work" if you remove the `innerHTML = ...;` assignments?  Since your template has the `{{ video.EncodingStatus }}` in it and I assume the `$scope.video` is referring an entry from the `data` object you work on in `populateVideoStatus`.

Comment: Also, what is controlling the interval that does the update?  I am beginning to suspect that you are resetting the `vm.videos` object which I assume has an `ng-repeat="video in vm.videos"` with the `ng-azuremediaplayer` nested underneath?

Comment: I have added the code for the interval. The Statuses are updating, but the issue is that the video player in the template gets reinitialized, since I am building it in the directive. And yes I am resetting vm.Videos, how else do I update the template?

Comment: right... so by resetting `vm.videos = ...` on an interval, it is probably causing the `ng-repeat` to rebuild itself and everything underneath.

Comment: Right, so what are my options for updating this? Have a secondary scope object and using that for the UI. I imagine this scenario is somewhat common.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120739/discussion-between-plong0-and-isaac-levin).